# How to change active buttons text colour?

Tags: javascript

How can I change active button text color to white and leave the other button's text color black while they are inactive?

```
<button class="tablink tab" onclick="openPrices('Ladies', this, '#0b0c0d')" id="defaultOpen">Ladies services</button>
<button class="tablink tab1" onclick="openPrices('Mens', this, '#0b0c0d')">Mens services</button>
<button class="tablink tab2" onclick="openPrices('Colour', this, '#0b0c0d')">Colour services</button>        

<script>
function openPrices(pricesName, elmnt, color) {
// Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

// Remove the background color of all tablinks/buttons
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
}

// Show the specific tab content
document.getElementById(pricesName).style.display = "block";

// Add the specific color to the button used to open the tab content
elmnt.style.backgroundColor = color;
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();         
</script>
```

Comment: @RGonzalez answer works but active color stay when you change but

Answer (score 0):

via javascript ->

```
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    tablinks[i].style.color = "black";

}

elmnt.style.color = "white";
```

or via CSS ->

```
.tablink{
  color:black;
}

.tablink.active {
   color: white;
}
```

and add/remove the active class to the element when you click on it:

```
tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablink");
for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].style.backgroundColor = "";
    tablinks[i].classList.remove = "active";    
}

elmnt.style.classList.add = "active";
```

Or a third option is to use a link () instead of a button, styled as a button, and make use of the different css selectors for  elements (:active , etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can use both CSS and Javascript for that, just use `:focus` for CSS or use `:active`. `:focus` will keep the color white until you click away, and `:active` will only keep the color while you are actively clicking on the button, I made a snipped you can test it out.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById("button1");
var button2 = document.getElementById("button2");
var button3 = document.getElementById("button3");

button1.onclick = function() {
  button1.style.color = "#fff";
  button2.style.color = "#000";
  button3.style.color = "#000";
}
button2.onclick = function() {
  button2.style.color = "#fff";
  button1.style.color = "#000";
  button3.style.color = "#000";
}
button3.onclick = function() {
  button3.style.color = "#fff";
  button1.style.color = "#000";
  button2.style.color = "#000";
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button1">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button2">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button3">Button1</button>
</body>
```

Or the CSS only way

```css
.btn {
  color: #000;
}

.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button1">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button2">Button1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button3">Button1</button>
</body>
```